# Javascript Issue with place text into text area correctly

Tags: javascript

Well edited this with the something tht looks much better thanks to Thomas W for a good example. I only altered it slightly but now seems to be working flawlessly. And Thomas now that ive learned and understand a new way to do something i wont be doing it the other way again. :) gonna change the code in the clearbox(form) soon too.

Thanks

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
window.onload = function(){
        windows1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        windows1.style.fontSize = "12pt";
        changetabs(1)
        }
var split_text;
var urls_1;
var numbercount=0;
var totals;
var check_time;
var wait = 0;
var itemCounter = 0;
var tabs=1;
var tabspicked=1;

    function addto_boxes(form) {
        split_text = document.getElementById("text_to_split").value;
        urls_1 = split_text.split(" ", 100000);
        totals = urls_1.length-1;
        var boxNum = 1;
        var x=0;
        while (x <= totals -1 ) {
            var box = document.getElementById( "input_box"+boxNum);
            box.value = box.value + urls_1[x] + " ";
            boxNum += 1;
            if (boxNum > tabspicked) boxNum = 1;
            x++;
            clearbox(this.form) 
        }
    }


    function clearbox(form) {
    document.getElementById("text_to_split").value = "";
    var input_box = document.getElementById("input_box1").value;
    var input_box_2 = document.getElementById("input_box2").value;
    var input_box_3 = document.getElementById("input_box3").value;
    var input_box_4 = document.getElementById("input_box4").value;
    var input_box_5 = document.getElementById("input_box5").value;
    var input_box_6 = document.getElementById("input_box6").value;
    var input_box_7 = document.getElementById("input_box7").value;
    var input_box_8 = document.getElementById("input_box8").value;
    var input_box_9 = document.getElementById("input_box9").value;
    var input_box_10 = document.getElementById("input_box10").value;
    urls = input_box.split(" ", 100000);
    urls2 = input_box_2.split(" ", 100000);
    urls3 = input_box_3.split(" ", 100000);
    urls4 = input_box_4.split(" ", 100000);
    urls5 = input_box_5.split(" ", 100000);
    urls6 = input_box_6.split(" ", 100000);
    urls7 = input_box_7.split(" ", 100000);
    urls8 = input_box_8.split(" ", 100000);
    urls9 = input_box_9.split(" ", 100000);
    urls10 = input_box_10.split(" ", 100000);
    document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = urls.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML = urls2.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box3").innerHTML = urls3.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box4").innerHTML = urls4.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box5").innerHTML = urls5.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box6").innerHTML = urls6.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box7").innerHTML = urls7.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box8").innerHTML = urls8.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box9").innerHTML = urls9.length-1;
    document.getElementById("box10").innerHTML = urls10.length-1;
    document.getElementById("displaytotal").innerHTML = urls.length-1 + urls2.length-1 + urls3.length-1 + urls4.length-1 + urls5.length-1 + urls6.length-1 + urls7.length-1 + urls8.length-1 + urls9.length-1 + urls10.length-1;
    }

    function bold_selected_tab(tab_to_bold) {
        document.getElementById("windows1").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows2").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows3").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows4").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows5").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows6").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows7").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows8").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows9").style.fontSize = "10pt";
        document.getElementById("windows10").style.fontSize = "10pt";

        document.getElementById("windows1").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows2").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows3").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows4").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows5").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows6").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows7").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows8").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows9").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        document.getElementById("windows10").style.fontWeight = "normal";
        tab_to_bold.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        tab_to_bold.style.fontSize = "12pt";
    }

    function changetabs(tabs) {
        document.getElementById("tabesselected").innerHTML = tabs;
        tabspicked = tabs;
    }


</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Select Number of tab to use. Tabs selected <b><span style="font-size:12pt" id="tabesselected"></span><br></b>
<input type="button" id="windows1" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 1" onclick="changetabs(1);bold_selected_tab(windows1);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows2" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 2" onclick="changetabs(2);bold_selected_tab(windows2);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows3" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 3" onclick="changetabs(3);bold_selected_tab(windows3);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows4" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 4" onclick="changetabs(4);bold_selected_tab(windows4);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows5" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 5" onclick="changetabs(5);bold_selected_tab(windows5);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows6" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 6" onclick="changetabs(6);bold_selected_tab(windows6);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows7" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 7" onclick="changetabs(7);bold_selected_tab(windows7);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows8" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 8" onclick="changetabs(8);bold_selected_tab(windows8);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows9" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs: 9" onclick="changetabs(9);bold_selected_tab(windows9);" />&#160;
<input type="button"id="windows10" style="height: 24px; width: 72px" value="Tabs 10" onclick="changetabs(10);bold_selected_tab(windows10);" /><br><br>
<input id="Split" type="button" value="Add to boxes" onclick="addto_boxes(this.form);"/>____<input id="clearbutton" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearbox(this.form);"/><Br><br>
Paste urls into this box and click add to boxes<br>
<textarea NAME="texttosplit" id="text_to_split" VALUE="" rows="4" cols="75"></textarea><br><br><br><br>


<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
<textarea NAME="inputbox" id="input_box1" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox2" id="input_box2" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox3" id="input_box3" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox4" id="input_box4" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox5" id="input_box5" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea><br>
<textarea NAME="inputbox6" id="input_box6" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox7" id="input_box7" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox8" id="input_box8" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox9" id="input_box9" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea>
<textarea NAME="inputbox10" id="input_box10" VALUE="" rows="2" cols="5"></textarea><br>
<INPUT TYPE="reset">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Also thanks Thomas because of your example i was also able to change the function bold_selected_tab() to. I think im getting the hang of it. Now if clearbox(form) function to look like the one below.

```
    function bold_selected_tab(tab_to_bold) {
        var x=1;
        while (x <= 10 ) {
            var box = document.getElementById("windows"+x);
            box.style.fontSize = "10pt ";
            x++;
        }

        var x=1;
        while (x <= 10 ) {
            var box = document.getElementById("windows"+x);
            box.style.fontWeight = "normal";
            x++;
        }

        tab_to_bold.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        tab_to_bold.style.fontSize = "12pt";
    }
```

Comment: You need to use loops & arrays, not this kind of stone-age repetition.  This is badly structured (lacking in structure). You've got 10 buttons, 10 textareas, all the code repeats 10 times.. this is horrible.

Comment: Don't dismiss JQuery when *you* are clearly a beginner, and don't know what you're doing. It's not the issue here, but you should probably pick it up -- code with it, is simpler & more reliable than without.

Comment: Thomas. wether it be repition or not... this is ONE way to do it. Just telling me to use loops and arrays doesn't help me. This is for personal use anyhow.... I'm not worried about how it "looks". Just need it to work properly. Also note that this is for a larger project... so arrays would mean an an entire recode. But you didnt take that into consideration? Thanks for nothing.

Comment: Well actually it already used loops and arrays. So before you go commenting you should probably look a little bit closer...

Comment: Do you want to distribute the space-delimited input strings, among N boxes? With your buttons up the top selecting N to divide these strings amongst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I say loops & arrays, I mean don't repeat your inner block 10 times.

```
var doneChecking = false;
for (var tab = 1; tab <= 10 && ! doneChecking; tab++) {
    if (tabspicked >= tab) {
        if (numbercount >= totals ){
            numbercount = 0;
            clearbox(this.form);
            doneChecking = true;
            break;
        }
        if (numbercount <= totals ){
            var elementId = "input_box"+tab;
            var urlIndex = numbercount + tab - 1;   // why?
            document.getElementById( elementId).value = document.getElementById( elementId).value + urls_1[ urlIndex] + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

The sooner you code this cleanly & properly, the sooner you'll understand what you're actually trying to do. You can either choose to try & learn this stuff, or not. Up to you.

If you're trying to distribute your space-delimited input strings, amongst N textboxes, you could do something like this.

```
var boxNum = 1;
var numBoxes = tabspicked;  // are these Boxes or Tabs? I'm calling them Boxes.
for (var url : urls_1) {
    // add to Current Box.
    var box = document.getElementById( "input_box"+boxNum);
    box.value = box.value + urls + " ";

    // advance Box, rotating around the N boxes.
    boxNum += 1;
    if (boxNum > numBoxes) boxNum = 1;
}
```

That should be a simple way of doing it. See how you go with that.

Comment: Well we all can't just magically know how to code all clean and neat etc. That comes with practice and application. What do you think i'm doing? Also that answer up there didn't even do anything that I can see. At least my clumsy code actually gave me a result of some sort. But thanks for trying.

Comment: My mistake. Missed something. :) But it wont continue adding stuff into the first box if you've selected less than 10. :P eg. type in a b c d e f g and select 3 it only puts a b c into the first 3 boxes then stops... so talk about me.

Comment: Thats method i can understand. Was trying to figure out how to do it. the method i had posted was one that worked. First one that came to mind. Can't seem to get the second one to work though. Not sure what im doing wrong. After adding that part in nothing is working... :( Everything that needs declaring is declared already.

Comment: With that example though I think I can do this now.... Im going to try and see what i can some up with. the for loop part i dont quite understand how it works but if i use `while (x >= totals)` I can also apply that to some other areas that need it.

Comment: Also @thomas figured out how to change the bold_selected_tab function too. I really appreciate the help a lot.